# I am trying to building an AM radio using SMD components

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, surface-mount, radio

I have a lot of SMD components, and I would like to build an AM radio using these components. I tried to search for radio circuit SMD, but doesn't exist. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Voted to close, as question is to broad. Of course you can build anything from SMD components - depends on the components you have at hand.

Comment: Not a superhet and not SMD but you might look at [this article](https://fbnews.jp/202202/w_shortbreak/). The ICs are cheap: [20 pcs on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Bridgold-20pcs-TA7642-7642-Radio/dp/B0B7667W12).

Comment: I need a base circuit to build myself, but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @FelipeLima You haven't listed the parts you have available. Nor have you indicated at what level of part you want to use (BJTs or compound IC devices.) And you haven't selected a type of AM radio (superhet or ?) Pretty broad question and very little guidances from you.

Comment: If you have a random collection of SMD parts @Felipe it likely does not include the bar antenna (the size of several sticks of gum). If you are a beginner, I would strongly recommend buying an [inexpensive AM radio kit like this one](https://www.amazon.com/Soldering-Learning-Practicing-Electronics-VOGURTIME/dp/B07YH8V2KS/ref=sr_1_4). But, note, because it contains some SMD parts ... I would think it a moderately difficult kit to complete successfully.

Comment: An AM radio can be as simple as diode and an earphone. Or it could use a frequency synthesizer, a phase-locked synchronous detector, and a big audio power amplifier. What do you imagine you're trying to build?

Comment: You can shrink the electronic components down to SMD, but you cannot shrink the antenna and ground to SMD. The best you can do is add ferrite to an antenna, but this still won't get the antenna down to SMD-size, and still have decent efficiency.

Comment: [**HERE**](https://www.google.com/search?sca_esv=602146624&sxsrf=ACQVn0-rBYZNgRjlDQ2FImJvQCSNnDVPQQ:1706445320067&q=simple+am+radio+using+discrete+components&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi9-YWZjICEAxVuqFYBHUUADV8Q0pQJegQICxAB&biw=1920&bih=942&dpr=2) are a large number of simple AM radio circuits. any are suitable for SMD construction. Each image links to a page.

Answer (score 3):

SMD and through-hole components can be used interchangeably for your AM radio. The usual reason that this isn't done is that the assembly of commercial products is done on automated equipment and this equipment will be best suited to SMD **or** through-hole but not both.

Use any AM radio circuit and use your SMD components if they suit.